# Python, Multiprocessing: what to do if process.join() waits forever?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a recursive function defined in a class. All the function does is parses text files, does some calculation and stores it in HDF5 files. It does not return anything.

Running it on one core is very slow. So I tried to use python's `multiprocessing` module. I am creating 4 processes and calling the same function inside a for loop with different arguments.

```
def main():

    f = FileIO() # class which does all the parsing and writing

    start_node = '2'
    maxDepth = 6

    procs = []

    start = time.time()    
    print "Entering for loop"
    for i in xrange(4):
        p = Process(target = f.read_and_write, args = (node+str(i), maxDepth))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)


    print "Exited for loop"
    for process in procs:
       process.join()

    end = time.time()

    print "Done in ", end - start, "seconds"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the reading and writing operations are done successfully and correctly. The only problem is my program does not exit. After printing `Entering for loop` I see nothing in console. From `htop` I can see the four cores have stopped working. But My program does not exit.

I don't know how to approach debugging this as I am new to using this `multiprocessing` module. My codes are logically correct and working just fine without using the `multiprocessing` module.

- How do I check the process status?
- How do I know where the code is stuck?

I am using `Python 2.7.10` | `Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)` | `ubuntu 14.04 LTS`

Any help on how to debug this kind problem is welcome.

Comment: What is happening in `f.read_and_write()`? Have you confirmed that execution is actually reaching the end of that function?

Comment: Its a recursive function which calls itself thousands of times. I don't know how to check whether execution is actually reaching the end of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should make sure that the processes will be finished. If they go into a wait state, then they will never be finished.

Second, even if those processes finish eventually, you might encounter forever waits, due to issues, like not getting the answer or the likes of that. You can pass a parameter to the `join` method, denoting the timeout. That would make sure that your main process will not wait forever.

Comment: If there is no `return` statement in a function it returns `none` once its job is done. What exactly happens when a process is finished? does it return anything or send some kind of signal?

Comment: When such a process is finished, you need to call task_done (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue.task_done) "If a join() is currently blocking, it will resume when all items have been processed (meaning that a task_done() call was received for every item that had been put() into the queue)."

Comment: I seemed like the problem was with my IDE (spyder). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LajosArpad What are the parameter join takes? Does it takes time in seconds?

Comment: @Leo as far as I know it is measured in seconds.